# C# custom TextChanged event handler for custom Text property for a UserControl?

Tags: c#, winforms, user-controls, event-handling

I created a custom User Control in C# and I added a custom Text property for my control. However I would also like raise an even whenever the value of my Text Property is changed and I want to call it `TextChanged`.

Here is my code for the property I created for my user control:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace TestControls
{
    public partial class Box: UserControl
    {
        public Box()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        [Bindable(true)]
        [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
        [Browsable(true)]
        [Category("Appearance")]
        public override string Text { get { return base.Text; } set { base.Text = value; this.Invalidate(); } }

        [Browsable(true)]
        public event EventHandler TextChanged;
    }
}
```

As you see I already created the `TextChanged` Event Handler but I don't know how to link it to the `Text` Property to make it to where when the value of 'Text' changes, the event will be raised.

Please be aware that I am using Windows Forms and I am not using WPF and I do not want to have to do anything that requires WPF. Every solution I have found for this issue has something to do with WPF or it does not completely solve my issue because they are not trying to create an event handler for a string. I don't understand how other people manage to do this but I would like to know how. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should call the event handler delegate manually in the setting of the `Text` property.

```
public partial class Box : UserControl
{
    public Box()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    [Bindable(true)]
    [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Visible)]
    [Browsable(true)]
    [Category("Appearance")]
    public override string Text
    {
        get { return base.Text; }
        set
        {
            if (base.Text != value)
            {
                base.Text = value; this.Invalidate();
                if(TextChanged != null)
                    TextChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty)
            }
        }
    }

    [Browsable(true)]
    public event EventHandler TextChanged;
}
```

Comment: you have no idea how much you just helped me. Thank you so much.

Comment: If you just want to handle `TextChanged` event, you don't need to do anything, the `UserControl` class has `TextChanged` which works properly. But it's not browsable, like its `Text` property.  If you want to make it browsable, as an alternative you can use custom event accessors (event properties).

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to handle `TextChanged` event, you don't need to do anything, the `UserControl` class has `TextChanged` which works properly. But it's not browsable, like its `Text` property.

If you want to make it browsable, as an alternative to the other answer, you can use custom event accessors (event properties) this way:

```
[Browsable(true)]
public event EventHandler TextChanged
{
    add { base.TextChanged += value; }
    remove { base.TextChanged -= value; }
}
```

To learn more about the syntax take a look at this MSDN resource:

- [How to: Implement Custom Event Accessors (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb882534.aspx)
- [How to: Handle Multiple Events Using Event Properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8843a9ch(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Also in customizing the `Text` property, instead of calling `this.Invalidate();` in the setter,a good option for such customization is putting them in `OnTextChanged` override.